# IP header explanation needed

Tags: c, network-programming, c-preprocessor

I have two codes which work exactly the same:

```
    struct sniff_ip {
        u_char ip_vhl;      /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
            ...
    };
#define IP_HL(ip)       (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
    #define IP_V(ip)        (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)
```

and

```
struct sniff_ip {
        uint8_t ip_hl:4;
        uint8_t ip_ver:4;
            ...
    };
```

The former is code from http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

Latter is mine

IP version and IP header length change position in these two codes, however the output is the same, why?

what I mean is `#define IP_HL(ip)   (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)` looks at second four bits, when `uint8_t ip_hl:4` is declared to capture first four bits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use bitfields for implementing protocols! Exact position depends on ABI and is platform/compiler dependent.

Your assumption

> when uint8_t ip_hl:4 is declared to capture first four bits

is wrong resp. is valid for your compiler but can not be generalized.  You have to read compiler/ABI documentation very carefully to find out where bits are really placed.

An example how bitfields are defined can be found in the ARM EABI specification http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf "7.1.7 Bit-fields".  But this might be completely different for x86 or mips ABIs

EDIT:

Bitfields can be useful to save space (e.g. `unsigned int flag:1` vs. `bool flag`) [this assumption might not hold because checks will need more (and slower) machine code] and to make code more easy to read (e.g. `if (a->flags & (1 << 0))` vs. `if (a->some_flag)`).  But you can never rely on exact positions.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it does not really answer my question :)

Comment: How ABI can affect position? I added __attribute__((__packed__)) to my structs and it seems like it woprks fine...

Comment: C standard does not specify how bitfields are to be implemented.  This is defined by the ABI.  `__packed` does not affect ordering of bitfields but removes padding and changes alignment.

Comment: Well I thought if it is declared first it accesses data first

Comment: It would be nice if you gave me some examples :)

Comment: and isn't it the same ABI which deals with both structs?

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP11-C.+Do+not+make+assumptions+regarding+the+layout+of+structures+with+bit-fields

Comment: @maximilliano: look at http://fossies.org/linux/privat/old/iputils-ss020927.tar.gz:a/iputils/include-glibc/netinet/ip.h , line 55.

Comment: Bit field layout is *UP TO THE COMPILER*.  Just because it works now implies that it will keep working in future versions.  Don't do it.  Your assumption about declaration implying order is only that -- IMPLIED.  It is not necessarily true.

Comment: I will mark yours as answer tomorrow, just to give time for other people to reply